# Creating lead values per group with dbplyr

Tags: r, dbplyr

My data contains mating data of cows I need to create lead values for a date variable per group because I want to aggregate the number of matings between two calving dates.

My code works perfectly with local data. However, the database is growing and it makes no sense to pull all data locally and run the code. I'm trying to use `dbplyr` to push my code to the server. However, this produces a, for me, uninformative error.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
agrosql <- getSQLdata(id=27)

calf <- tbl(agrosql,"T_Animal_Calvings")

# Sort on chronolgically per animal
calf <- arrange(calf,AnimalID,CalvingDate)

# Create lead calving date
calf %<>% 
  group_by(AnimalID) %>%
  mutate(leadcalf=lead(CalvingDate))
```

The error message is:

> ```
> Error: <SQL> 'SELECT  TOP 11 "MatingID", "CalvingID", "AnimalID", "AnimalServerID", "AnimalNo", "SortAnimalNo", "MatingDate", "MatingDateDT", "MatingType", "MatingTypeName", "MatingTime", "MatingEndDate", "MatingEndDateDT", "BullAnimalID", "BullName", "BullRegistrationId", "EmbryoMotherAnimalID", "EmbryoMotherName", "EmbryoMotherRegistrationId", "IsSexed", "IsOwnStock", "ChargeNo", "DosisQuantity", "EventCommentAbbr", "StaffMatingRelationID", "StaffMatingShortName", "StaffMatingRelationType", "StaffMatingRelationTypeName", "HasAssumedFlush", "ConceptionDate", "ConceptionDateDT", "ServiceNo", "NextMatingID", "LastPregnantDate", "LastPregnantDateDT", "FirstNotPregnantDate", "FirstNotPregnantDateDT", "IsMatingWithFlushing", "IsMatingWithEmbryoImplant", "IsMatingWithFertilityAbortion", LEAD("MatingDate", 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY "AnimalID" ORDER BY "AnimalID", "MatingDate") AS "leadai"
> FROM (SELECT *
> FROM "T_Animal_Matings"
> ORDER BY "AnimalID", "MatingDate") "mztkpapjhp"'
>  nanodbc/nan
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The way your SQL query is structured, you have a sub-query that contains an `ORDER BY` statement. SQL does not accept `ORDER BY` in sub-queries.

The `ORDER BY` clause is due to your use of dplyr's `arrange` function.

If you want to apply an order to lag/lead you do this inside the lag/lead command. Try the following:

```
calf %>% 
  group_by(AnimalID) %>%
  mutate(leadcalf = lead(CalvingDate,
                         order_by = c("calf", "AnimalID", "CalvingDate"))
```